# Is there a way to check a condition is met in excel for once using countifs in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to check if A1 > B1 by changing the values and output in C1 eg: True or False. There is a possibility of a condition can be met twice. I need to check the first occurence between these two cells A1 and B1.

This is the formula used

=IF(A1>=B1,"TRUE","FALSE")

In the first row. Where value of B1 is dynamic.

```
1st time: A1 = 5, B1 = 10 // Output False -- Right

2nd time: A1 = 5, B1 = 2  // Output True. -- Wrong 

3rd time: A1 = 5, B1 = 12 // Output False. -- Wrong
```

In the above explanation, I want to get the first condition and freeze the next iteration.

Comment: This more of an open-ended request than a question. Please edit your question to include a sample of the data with the formula you have (working or not). This helps in providing an answer.

Comment: So "=A1=B1" entered in cell C1 will give True or False.

Comment: @SolarMike can you explain to me as I tried your solution but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

So, with a picture of the sheet using your example plus an extra one:

[image]

either:

```
=A1>B1
```

or

```
=A1>=B1
```

Comment: You added values in A2, B2 and A3, B3. I am just expecting the output with only two cells A1 and B1. Where value of B1 is only going to change and A1 will remain the same. Is it possible as I am a newbie to excel. I have added all the instances with A1 and B1

Comment: If you enter the formula as I did then you can change the contents of B1 as often as you wish and C1 will show the result each time.

Comment: My question is if at the first time the output is false then whatever might be the second dynamic value it should not change the output. According to my question if first time it is false then what ever the values change in B1 the value of C1 should be false only